# Typescript, auto await all Promise-returning function calls

Tags: typescript, async-await

I am using "async" function and sometimes I am forgetting to add "await" for calls inside:

```
async function doThreeSteps () => {
    await firstPromiseReturningFunc();
    nonAsyncFunction();
    secondPromiseReturningFunc(); //Error here! Need to wait until this call resolves
    someOtherStepWhichReliesOnSuccessfullEndingOfPreviousFunction();
}
```

It should be possible for TypeScript to warn about such error because TS knows what type does each function returns, is it promise or value.
I'd like to make TS to warn me about such cases. Is it possible?

Comment: If you define type of `x3`, compiler should throw an error

Comment: Always add types to your variables. Eliminates most of these mistakes.

Comment: Sorry, now updated. Your suggestions about variables types are 100% correct, but not suitable for updated problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

typescript-eslint (https://typescript-eslint.io) has the "no-floating-promises" rule. It requires that *something* be done with a Promise returned from a function such as .then, .catch, await, assignment, or return.