# No floating promises check in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, promise

I have an asynchronous function, returning a promise. Now I want TypeScript to check if I resolve the promises. If ever I missed adding await it should show a warning. How can I do that?

```
export const getData = async (id: number): Promise<number> => {
  return axios.get(
    `/api/human/${id}`
  );
};

// Should show error as await is missing
console.log(getData(1));

// Should just work
console.log(await getData(2));
```

Maybe this can not be achieved with Typescript but `eslint`. Then please help me out how to do that way.

If the only option is `no-floating-promises` [from tslint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748342/typescript-auto-await-all-promise-returning-function-calls), this is not helping, as it is deprecated and not used in my code base.

Update: As @son-nguyen pointed out awaiting axios and then casting a promise is redundant. So I removed the await for it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's the changes I've made in my Typescript project in order to make ESLint warn me when I forget to add `await` to an async call.

.eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ...
    project: './tsconfig.eslint.json',
  },
  rules: {
    ...
    '@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises': ['error'],
  },
}
```

tsconfig.eslint.json

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    ...
    ".eslintrc.js", // ESLint's config must be included
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, `parserOptions: {
    ...
    project: './tsconfig.json'
  }` worked for me

Comment: This makes linting overal much slower, didn't you experience that?

Answer (score 1):

`getData` clearly declared that it returns a Promise, while you return an `await`ed value, which is not a Promise. The `await getData()` call is then problematic but the type check does not fail because a static value is safe to cast as a Promise (by simple resolving to it). It works without problem, but it does not look right because as a rule when you return a Promise (which you get from the `axios.get()` call), you don't need to `await` it, which a good editor will warn you.

Removing `await` now makes the result of `getData()` truly a Promise, you can use it as usual, either passing down the chain or `await`ing to get the final value. The benefit is now the compiler or linter know your intent better and can give better advice.

```
export const getData = async (id: number): Promise<number> => {
  return axios.get(
    `/api/human/${id}`
  );   // returns a true Promise to be awaited outside
};
```

Comment: You are right, but this was just a bad example. I really wanted to know how to be aware of the promise using it somewhere else.

Comment: I don't think there's such thing as a "true" promise. async functions *always* return a promise, no matter if you return it directly or indirectly (by awaiting it in the function's body). 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function